# Budget constraint hyperplanes

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

This question relates to a [specific paper by Eric Budish, published in 2011 in JPE](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/eric.budish/research/budish-approxceei-jpe-2011.pdf), but I've tried to put all relevant information in this question. On page 1072, he defines *budget constraint hyperplanes* as follows:

> Let $H(i,x) = \{\mathbf{p}:\mathbf{p} \cdot x = b_i \}$ denote the
>   hyperplane in $M$-dimensional price space along which agent $i$ can
>   exactly afford bundle $x$. As prices cross $H(i,x)$ from below, bundle
>   $x$ goes from being affordable for $i$ to being unaffordable for $i$.

$\textbf{p}$ represents a price vector for the $M$ goods, which, importantly, are indivisible. $b_i$ is agent $i$'s budget. I think the rest is sufficiently self-explanatory. My confusion is with this subsequent statement:

> Importantly, the number of such hyperplanes is finite because the
>   number of agents and the number of bundles are finite. This is an
>   advantage of having only indivisible goods.

This I don't see. For example, suppose $M=2$. Then aren't all $\textbf{p}=(\alpha b_i, (1-\alpha)b_i)$ such that $\alpha \in [0,1]$ hyperplanes meeting that definition, and thus I have infinitely many?

Having said that, a hyperplane is the set of those price vectors, not each of the vectors, so maybe the full set of price vectors I've just described together define just one hyperplane? I suppose my issue is understanding what a hyperplane is in this setting, and how the indivisibility gives us just a finite set of hyperplanes to work with. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think the key here is that he is fixing the bundle $x$. Notice the hyperplane is a function of which agent it is $i$ and what bundle he wants $x$. Might be helpful to stick to your $\mathcal{R}^2$ example and use $x = (1, 1)$ and $i$ gives us $b_i = B$. This should give you something like $H(i, x) = \{ p | p_1 = B - p_2 \}$ (where notationally I'm writing $p = (p_1, p_2) \in \mathcal{R}^2$). Does that help?

Comment: That does help a little - thanks. So in $\mathcal{R}^2$, a hyperplane is a line, though, right? And then for it to exactly equal the budget that line must go through $x$. But then, why can't I pivot that line around $x$ by a few degrees and call it a new hyperplane? What he describes as a hyperplane, $H(i,x)$, seems more like a set of hyperplanes to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Exactly, a hyperplane in $\mathcal{R}^2$ is a line. Are you thinking about the hyperplane being in price space or goods space? $x$ isn't in the same space as the hyperplane, so I don't know what you mean pivot the line around $x$.

Comment: I'm thinking of a space with two goods where $x$ is the $(1,1)$ coordinate. I'm thinking of the budget constraint hyperplane/line as being any line that goes through that point. Basically, I'm thinking of the standard intro micro plot with apples, oranges, and a budget constraint. I realize the budget set is just the vertices, not the hull, because the goods are indivisible.

Comment: This hyperplane is in the price space which means the axis that it would be plotted on are $p_1$ and $p_2$ so you can't really plot $x$ with this hyperplane

Comment: Indeed. OK - progress. Let me ponder this now with that added insight. OK, so then suppose $b_i=B$ and $x=(1,1)$. Then $H(i,x)$ is just a line going from $(0,B)$ to $(B,0)$ in the price space, yes?

Comment: And then the reason we may have infinitely many of these with divisible goods is just that there are infinitely many $x$, which is not true in the finite indivisible goods case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{\mathbb{p}:\exists \alpha \in (0,1), \mathbb{p}_1=\alpha b_i, \mathbb{p}_2=(1-\alpha)b_i\}$ coincides with the hyperplane $\{\mathbb{p}:p_1+p_2=b_i\}$, therefore you are not finding extra hyperplanes by doing this and varying $\alpha$.

More generally, if you fix $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $b_i$, you obtain one hyperplane characterized by the equation $\{\mathbb{p}:p_1 x_1+p_2 x_2=b_i\}$. Since there are finitely many such $x$ (and $b_i$ is given), there are finitely many such hyperplanes.